# We should make a list of 'basic', 'moderate', and 'expert' challenges

Tags: discussion, new-users

<sup>Somewhat related to [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tags-regarding-difficulty) question on creating tags regarding difficulty</sup>

<sup>To any duplicate/down voters, see [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14905/we-should-make-a-list-of-basic-mediocre-and-expert-challenges#comment54504_14905) commment</sup>

When I first came to this site, I had no idea on how anything worked, and I wasn't that great at golfing, I only knew python and I had never used it for anything like this. I can only assume this is how most new users feel. If they come to the homepage and see mostly difficult challenges, most likely they won't come back. I say we should have a running list on meta of basic, moderate, and expert challenges. **Obviously this is subjective**. This can just be a suggested difficulty rating.

- For instance, [Add two numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84260/add-two-numbers), [Don't google 'google'](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58891/dont-google-google), and [Fibonacci Sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence) could all go under basic, since these challenges require little to no thought in *most* programming languages. There are certainly notable exceptions, but for standard golfing/everyday languages, these are extremely simple.
- Challenges to go under the moderate list could be [Find number of ones to get a number using + and *](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/154236/find-number-of-ones-to-get-a-number-using-and), [Can you outgolf Bill Gates?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155650/can-you-outgolf-bill-gates), and [When do I get my sandwich?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/141675/when-do-i-get-my-sandwich)
- Finally, the expert list could contain such challenges like [Build a digital clock in Conway's Game of Life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/88783/build-a-digital-clock-in-conways-game-of-life), [Regex that only matches itself](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28821/regex-that-only-matches-itself), and [Upgoat or Downgoat?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71631/upgoat-or-downgoat)

**Basically they would be sorted based on amount of time required to answer in a reasonable language**

These lists would just be for reference so people who are new to the site can find challenges to suit them, they often wouldn't know what to search for to get an easier challenge. It could maybe be linked to when a new user makes a first post.

What are your opinions on this? Improvements? Let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tags regarding difficulty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tags-regarding-difficulty). I know you've linked to it in your post, but this is a very similar idea, and, in my eyes, a duplicate.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing nah this is just a starting list of challenges in a meta post, maybe holding 30 per list, whereas I believe he was proposing tagging every challenge with a difficulty tag

Comment: One potential problem with this idea is that [tag:basic] challenges, such as *add two numbers* can't realistically be answered in *typical* languages, because there are already so many answers.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem True, but new esolangs that aren't super hard to use are being created all the time

Comment: Mediocre. I do not think you want that word. Maybe "Moderate" instead.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork, "mediocre" is a good description, if perhaps generous, for some of the named "challenges". "Add two numbers", for example.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Mediocre could certainly apply to some challenges, however I did indeed mean moderate

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5842/code-golf-tutorials)

Answer (score 5):

The problem with curating such a list is that someone has to maintain it. There are so many new questions on a regular basis that eventually the list may become orphaned.

A suggestion that I'd like to make that might align with this is to adapt the format of a blog and release a set of around 5~20 questions that are similar in difficulty (and preferably "new" as well, so it isn't already flooded with answers) once in a while, and direct users to it for finding material to train on. Some sets might be "basic", some sets might be "hard", but at least a consistent, easy to manage format might keep it at a size that will actually appear useful to someone.

Comment: I like this idea, but I think it should have a minimum of 10 questions to provide some options